# Convert ASCII decimal to string

Tags: javascript, decimal, ascii, decode

I have a string in representation of ASCII decimal stored in a column in my db:

```
[104 105]
```

this converts to `hi`.

I need to be able to convert my column into string representation.

I know I can use `String.fromCharCode(num,...num+1)` but it doesn't quite work for me.

I would need to parse and split my db column value `[104 105]` into two separate vars:

```
var num1 = 104;
var num2 - 105;
```

this doesn't work when I have a complex ASCII decimal representation.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? My input would be something like `[104 105 243 0 0 255...]` which is in ASCII decimal and I need to get the string representation.

Comment: Those input values are not valid JavaScript literal values. It would have to be `[104,105]` to be an array of bytes. Please [edit] your question with how you are receiving the data in JavaScript. The easiest is probably `console.log(JSON.stringify(value, null, 2))`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse that string first, by removing the `[]` characters, splitting at spaces, and converting the array elements to numbers.

```js
let num_string = '[104 105]';
let nums = num_string.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '').split(' ').map(Number);
let string = String.fromCharCode(...nums);
console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the codes using [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regex, and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return an array of the converted codes. Just [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array into a string at the end.

```js
function convert(str, re) {
  return str.match(/(\d+)/g).map(code => {
    return String.fromCharCode(code);
  }).join('');
}

console.log(convert('[104 105]'));
console.log(convert('[104 105 243 0 0 255]'));
```